# cut or remove the PlaneGeometry through coordinates xy

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new in Three.js and I want to do like this:

```
const myPlaneGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(
    width,
    height,
    widthSegments,
    heightSegments
);

if(myPlaneGeometry.x > 2 && myPlaneGeometry.y > 3){
    myPlaneGeometry.cut(x , y) // remove
}
```

Performance is important for me in more complex shapes.
Thanks for any simple idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the clipping feature of three.js, which allows you to define one or more planes that will clip the geometry of any object that intersects with them.

The solution is to use a bounding box to limit the 3D space of your object.

```
// Create a bounding box for the object
var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(myObject);

// Calculate the center of the bounding box
var center = new THREE.Vector3();
boundingBox.getCenter(center);

// Create a helper object to visualize the bounding box
var helper = new THREE.Box3Helper(boundingBox, 0xffff00);

// Add the helper object to the scene
scene.add(helper);

// update code.
// Create a bounding box for the object
var boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(myObject);

// Remove any objects that intersect with the bounding box
for (var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var object = scene.children[i];
    if (object.type === 'Mesh' && boundingBox.intersectsBox(new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object))) {
        scene.remove(object);
    }
}
```

My code will result in a plane geometry that has a box-shaped hole in it.

Comment: I think clipping Planes solution is not perfect for me. I need a thing be limited in 3D space and rotatable and I can change it's position.

Comment: check my updated code.

Comment: Now this is good but how can to remove anythings inside the box3?

Comment: check my code again.